# Return file ID if file exists in WordPress media folder by using REST API

Tags: python, wordpress, rest

I use Python urllib.request module to post to WordPress. I have SOME.PDF in local folder. How can I send request to WordPress REST API to check if file already exists in media folder or not. I want to get file ID back if it is already in media folder. I don't want to clutter media folder with duplicate files. Thank you.

Comment: did you try writing any code?

Comment: Unortunately I don't have any clue about specific media requests. But I was able to post media and and text

Comment: I wanted to use something like this http://site ..../wp-json/wp/v2/media/file.pdf but it does not work

Comment: You'll likely need to write a custom endpoint for this because -as you already figured out- the built-in ones can't find file data by filename.

Comment: @cabrerahector thank you

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by just sending request to URL pattern like following:

http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?search=file-name-minus-extension

if response is empty it means no such file uploaded.
If there is a file it returns essential information about this file (ID and etc.)

Thank you all for your time.

Example in Python 3.x and WordPress REST API

```
import requests
import re
import json

def check_media(filename):

# Regex gilename to format like in WordPress media name
file_name_minus_extension = re.sub(r'\'|(....$)','', filename, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

response = requests.get(
'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?search=' + file_name_minus_extension,
headers= # input_your_headers  
)

try:
    result = response.json()
    file_id = int(result[0]['id'])
    return file_id
except IndexError:
    print('No such file in Wordpress media folder: ' + filename)
```